# Most efficient way to query and update dynamoDb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo DB table that will be used for storing failed requests, at a later time another lambda will want to read the requests and reprocess them.

At the minute I am creating the table like this using typescript CDK

```
const myTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, "my-table", {
      tableName: "my-table-name",
      partitionKey: { name: "file_id", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
    });
```

I am sending data into the table like this in a python lambda

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name=region)
my_table = dynamodb.Table("my-table-name")

failedRecord = {
        "file_id": str(file_id),
        "processed": "false",
        "payload": str(payload),
    }

    my_table.put_item(Item=failedRecord)
```

Now what I want to do from another lambda is for all the entries in the table with processed = false I want read them, do something with them and then update their processed = true.

Do I need to add a secondary index here to be efficient. An example of how to do this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider creating a global secondary index that contains *only* unprocessed items.  You would add/remove items from the GSI by adding/removing the GSI Primary Key.  For example, consider the following table structure:

[image]

Notice that only `file_id` 3 and 4 have a GSIPK defined.  The GSI would logically look like this:

[image]

DynamoDB would only project items into the index where the GSIPK exists on that item.  Your lambda could read from the GSI, do some work, set the `processed` attribute to `true` and remove the `GSIPK` value. This would effectively remove the item from the secondary index.

The `update` call to DynamoDB to do this would look something like this:

```
 const params = {
    TableName: YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE,
    Key: {
      PK: FILE_ID_HERE
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #processed = :true REMOVE #gsipk",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#processed": "processed",
      "#gsi1pk": "GSIPK",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":true": true
    }
  };

  ddbClient.update(params);
```

Comment: This looks like a promising solution i am going to try now, can I ask do you think this would be a better solution than setting processed as the global secondary index and querying looking for false values then updating them to true after processing?

Comment: There are certainly many ways you could address this access pattern.  Indexing on processed could work as well.  I'd suggest giving it a try and seeing how it works for your use case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `filenote_id` is already unique (it should given that you have set it as Partition Key), with the record format that you have shared and table schema a GSI without also adding a Sort key would not make any difference.

A different approach that you could consider is enabling [DynamoDB Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) for the Table in question and set it as a [trigger of the second Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html).
With this approach you'd be essentially capturing all activities on the table and in your logic you could filter out all events that are not `INSERT` and process the ones you are interested into at your own pace.

This way you'd avoid querying the table entirely.

Comment: I don't think streams will work here we want to trigger that second lambda on a schedule or when a legacy service has become available again. If we trigger lambda as soon as they go in they are likely to fail again.

Comment: I understand. Is there any reason at all why you want to use DynamoDB? Why not put these failed requests in a SQS Queue for instance and have the second lambda function poll this queue whenever necessary and store in DynamoDB only the final result?

Comment: You could store the actual request payload on S3 as a JSON and put only the object key in a message in SQS. If they are that big, in order to query them from DynamoDB you’ll have to do a first query to retrieve their ID only (basically exclude payload from selected attributes) and then handle one by one of them with a get_item. The reason for this being DynamoDB also having size caps at 4MB per query.

Comment: [This is the pattern I was referring to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html), I know the use case here is detailed in Java but you can implement the same in Python pretty easily.

Comment: The reason we are using dynamo as opposed to SQS is because we don't want to have duplicate requests coming from the queue, if a new failed request for file_id=A144 comes to dynamo we can update the entry in the DB rather than add to an SQS queue where we might have multiple requests to update the same filenote and only the last one in the queue is relevant if that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry deleted the message about the 256KB its actually not the reason we are using dynamo here

Comment: Alright, that’s a relevant piece of info that could have been in the question, but maybe also my fault for going off topic. To answer your question again, in order to set a GSI you’ll have to specify a sort key which you currently don’t have. If you keep the file_id as PK and choose status as SK you’ll be able to query them effectively. Data will physically be stored partitioned by file_id and be sorted by status, making a query more efficient assuming you query one status at the time.

Comment: But you don't think there is a need to add one in this case? Could you add a code snippet of what you think is the most efficient way to read the items with processed=false and the to update them with processed=true after processing them?